# How to print a PDF file from my Android app with a shared printer

Tags: android

Here is the code that I attempted to implement. Set up the environment:

```
File createfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PDFfolder/");
createfile.mkdirs();
File outputFile = new File(createfile, "Sample.pdf");
fileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
byte[] decodedByte = Base64decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PDFfolder/Sample.pdf";
OutputStream pdffos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);pdf

fos.write(decodedByte);
pdffos.flush();
pdffos.close();
```

Now try to print:

```
File file = new File(filepath);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
ApplicationManager.getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a little presentation effort? may be making your code actually readable?

Answer (score 2):

On Android 4.4+, you are welcome to use the [printing API](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html).

On older devices, you would need to ask the printer manufacturer if they have any means of supporting printing from Android, or use something like Google Cloud Print.